# How to set a position of colorbox?

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to place a colorbox under the x-axis under the xlabel. I means it should start under the 0 and end under the 22.

```
set colorbox horiz user origin .1,.02 size .8,.04
```

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the coordinate system `graph`:

```
set bmargin 8
set colorbox horiz user origin graph 0,screen .08 size graph 1,screen .04
plot x w l lc pal
```